# Trying to integrate PayPal checkout express, using classes\dll provided by PayPal, getting: Could not load file or assembly 'log4net

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, api, .net-4.0

Using .Net framework 4. I am assuming this log4net version that the PayPal library is dependent on
requires an older version or I don't have the file at all? Do I need to get this file somewhere or
is there another work around ?

Update, after installing latest version of log4net I now get the same error except the file is found
this time and says**:

```
 The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
   com.paypal.sdk.profiles.BaseAPIProfile..cctor() +0




Line 23:        {
Line 24:            NVPCallerServices caller = new NVPCallerServices();
Line 25:            **IAPIProfile profile = ProfileFactory.createSignatureAPIProfile();**
```

code.

```
Stack Trace: 


[FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.0.30714, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b32731d11ce58905' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.]
   com.paypal.sdk.profiles.BaseAPIProfile..cctor() +0
```

---

```
[TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'com.paypal.sdk.profiles.BaseAPIProfile' threw an exception.]
   com.paypal.sdk.profiles.BaseAPIProfile..ctor() +0
   com.paypal.sdk.profiles.SignatureAPIProfile..ctor() +29
   com.paypal.sdk.profiles.ProfileFactory.createSignatureAPIProfile() +39
   GenerateCodeNVP.ECSetExpressCheckout.ECSetExpressCheckoutCode(String returnURL, String cancelURL, String amount, String paymentType, String currencyCode) in C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MyProject\DotNetNVPGenerate\ECSetExpressCheckout.cs:25
   NeoCart.WebUI.Controllers.CheckoutController.Payment() in C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MyProject\NeoCart.WebUI\Controllers\CheckoutController.cs:179
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +96
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log4net is a [separate open-source project](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/).

You can get it from within Visual Studio [using NuGet](http://nuget.org/packages/log4net), or you can download it from Apache's website.

Comment: Even after installing, it's a newer version so does not work. Is it possible to download older ones using the Package Manager Console?

Comment: Thanks, but know where I can find one that will satisfy the 1.2.0.30714 version required by the PayPal library? Because the 1.2.10 gives the same error.

Comment: I don't know.  Try to find a newer version of the PayPal library, ort recompile it from source against the newest log4net.

Answer (score 1):

This question is a little old, but wanted to let you know, I was having the same issue, and found the proper library for this issue. You'll want to go to the Beta 8 archive for the sourceforge project here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/log4net/files/log4net/1.2.0%20Beta8/

Download this repository, and look in log4net-1.2.0-beta8\log4net-1.2.0-beta8\bin\net\1.0\release, the log4net.dll has the version 1.2.0.30714

Even if you don't use this, someone else might run into this question, and hopefully this response will help fix the issue for anyone else.